# last point in page pipeline to change culture?

Tags: asp.net, culture, pipeline

What is the last point in the asp.net page loading pipeline that I can change the culture of a page by doing the following?

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = << new culture >>;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = << new culture >>;
```

I am changing the culture in my code and want to know at what point is the last point in which I can change the pages culture so that the correct resource files etc are picked up.

Is the Page PreInit too late in the pipeline to change the culture? I am aware there is an InitialiseCulture method in the Page class but I am working outside of this.

Comment: sorry to not directly address your question but you state you want to change the pages culture.  This would be done from the Page.UICulture or Page.Culture properties.  The method you are following looks more like a windows forms approach, but I may not understand your reasons.  you can overide the InitializeCulture() method set the culture and then call the base.InitializeCulture().  As far as the last point to change the culture of the thread in the page life cycle, Im unsure what your objectives are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per MSDN documentation, correct way is to use `InitialiseCulture` - it gets called very early in page life-cycle before even controls are created. And that is even before `PreInit` event.

Said that, people have set the culture information as late as `Page_Load` event. For example, see [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306162) or this [code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ChangeCultures.aspx). So I guess that PreInit event should be ok.

There are two relevant properties - Culture and UICulture. AFAIK, UICulture is used for loading correct local (page specific)/global resources and that would be done at rendering stage - so should not be an issue. The culture info from thread get used by many frameworks methods and you need to be careful using any code that is dependent on the culture information before you sets the culture in page life cycle - example of such code can be formatting of data or parsing from request data etc.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment to your original post too.

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    UICulture = "en";
    Culture   = "en-US";
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx